# The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created a procedure (using SQL Server 2008) to retrieve the image data from `image` table but this procedures giving me an error

> "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted,
>   except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator."

My procedure is this:

```
Create procedure [dbo].[xp_GetImage]
@companyId  udtId
as  
begin

/*=============================================================================
*   Constants
*============================================================================*/
declare 
        @SUCCESS            smallint,
        @FAILED             smallint,
        @ERROR_SEVERITY     smallint,
        @ERROR_STATE1       smallint,
        @theErrorMsg        nvarchar(4000),
        @theErrorState      int,
        @chartCount         int,
        @provider           varchar(128),
        @projectCount       int

select  
        @SUCCESS    =   0,  
        @FAILED     =   -1, 
        @ERROR_SEVERITY = 11,
        @ERROR_STATE1 = 1

begin try

    -- Get the Image

    select  Logo, LogoName,LogoSize
              from CompanyLogo                  
     where CompanyId = @companyId         
  order by Logo desc

end try


begin catch
    set @theErrorMsg = error_message()
    set @theErrorState = error_state()
    raiserror (@theErrorMsg, @ERROR_SEVERITY, @theErrorState)
    return (@FAILED)
end catch
end 
print 'created the procedure xp_GetImage'
go
---end of the procedure
grant EXECUTE on xp_GetImage to public
go
```

please help me.

Comment: Also: *ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. **Avoid using these data types in new development work**, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.* [see MSDN docs for more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget about CAST(). It just got me out of trouble looking for a string in a text field, viz

```
SELECT lutUrl WHERE CAST(Url AS varchar) = 'http://www.google.com.au'
```

The blurb that helped me is at [Mind Chronicles](http://twogeeks.mindchronicles.com/?p=7). The author discusses the sorting issue as well.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make sense to sort (order) by binary image data. Why don't you sort by one of the other columns instead?

**Example**

Modify the code from this:

```
-- Get the Image

  SELECT Logo, LogoName,LogoSize
    FROM CompanyLogo                  
   WHERE CompanyId = @companyId         
ORDER BY Logo desc
```

To this:

```
-- Get the Image

  SELECT Logo, LogoName,LogoSize
    FROM CompanyLogo                  
   WHERE CompanyId = @companyId         
ORDER BY LogoName
```